# Yammer Javascript SDK usage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, content-security-policy, yammer

I'm working with the Yammer Javascript SDK. In the documentation, it says to use the following script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="YOUR-APP-CLIENT-ID" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
```

I've added that, but it gives me the following error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

How do I fix this? It was working fine before. I haven't made any changes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src
 Might have what you need.

Comment: Thank you @Polymer! Feel free to post this as an answer. :)

Comment: I'm using an example off https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP, which would show the example syntax `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';">` Will have to change for script, however it should work with that syntax. So, try adding the `'self';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to CSP (Content Security Policy). Relevant information can be found here for script related CSP:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src

And here, for more info about general CSP:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP